# Need help with Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void parentIDs(Id)

Tags: apex, trigger

I am working on a trigger and I receive the Method does not exist problem, for the following line of code: `parentIds(crdLine.Credit_Request__c);`. Any thoughts on the issue. Problem states `void parentIds(Id)`

```
trigger MakingApprovalRequiredTrigger on Credit_Lines__c (After Insert, After Update, After Delete){

Map<Id, List<Credit_lines__c>> parentIds = new Map<id, List<credit_lines__c>>();

If(Trigger.IsInsert || Trigger.IsUpdate){
    For(Credit_Lines__c crdLine : Trigger.New){
        If(crdLine.Credit_Request__c != Null){
            parentIds(crdLine.Credit_Request__c);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

parentIds is a map so you cannot just pass a parameter in it but rather you have to put values in them. For ex in your code-

```
trigger MakingApprovalRequiredTrigger on Credit_Lines__c (After Insert, After Update, After Delete){

Map<Id, List<Credit_lines__c>> parentIds = new Map<id, List<credit_lines__c>>();

If(Trigger.IsInsert || Trigger.IsUpdate){
    For(Credit_Lines__c crdLine : Trigger.New){
        If(crdLine.Credit_Request__c != Null){
            //Creating a temporary list so that it can reinitialised with every new coming value in for loop and can be put in map
            List<Credit_lines__c> tempCreditLines = new list<Credit_lines__c>();

            //Checking if map already contains key for crdLine.Credit_Request__c
            if(parentIds.conTainsKey(crdLine.Credit_Request__c)){
                //If map already contains key for crdLine.Credit_Request__c then taking the existing list
                tempCreditLines = parentIds.get(crdLine.Credit_Request__c);
            }

            //Adding the coming credit record to list
            tempCreditLines.add(crdLine);

            //put value in map for the list created above and the key crdLine.Credit_Request__c
            parentIds.put(crdLine.Credit_Request__c, tempCreditLines);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand, you're trying to sort a list of `Credit_lines__c` by `Credit_Request__c`.

You should start by reading the documentation about the put method of the [Map class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm).

You have to check first if the `Id` is already in your map.
Then, if so, you have to add a new record to the list.
If not, you have to put a whole new list containing your record in your Map.

Here's the right code:

```
for(Credit_Lines__c crdLine : Trigger.New){
        If(crdLine.Credit_Request__c != Null){
            if(parentIds.containsKey(crdLine.Credit_Request__c)){
                 parentIds.get(crdLine.Credit_Request__c).add(crdLine);
            }else{
                 List<Credit_lines__c> creditLines = new List<Credit_lines__c>{crdLine};
                 parentIds.put(crdLine.Credit_Request__c, creditLines);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Hey Martin I guess parentIds(crdLine.Credit_Request__c); will not be there as this is a map.